# All Moq testCases pass without checking any logic?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, moq-3

I am following this [intro to unit testing](https://www.codementor.io/copperstarconsulting/intro-to-unit-testing-c-code-with-nunit-and-moq-part-1-y2b9iv8iq) tutorial.

I have not implemented a logic to determine what credit score should return "Maybe", "Declined" but **Moq** test passes all the Unit Tests.

```
public interface ICreditDecisionService {
    string GetCreditDecision(int creditScore);
}

public class CreditDecision {
ICreditDecisionService creditDecisionService;

public CreditDecision(ICreditDecisionService creditDecisionService) {
    this.creditDecisionService = creditDecisionService;
}

public string MakeCreditDecision(int creditScore) {
    return creditDecisionService.GetCreditDecision(creditScore);
}

===================================
// Testing Class
[TestFixture]
public class CreditDecisionTests {
    //mock instance for dependency
    Mock < ICreditDecisionService > mockCreditDecisionService;

    CreditDecision systemUnderTest;

    [TestCase(100, "Declined")]
    [TestCase(549, "Declined")]
    [TestCase(550, "Maybe")]
    [TestCase(674, "Maybe")]
    [TestCase(675, "We look forward to doing business with you!")]
    public void MakeCreditDecision_Always_ReturnsExpectedResult(int creditScore, string expectedResult) {

        //Arrange
        //creating and configuring the mock 
        mockCreditDecisionService = new Mock < ICreditDecisionService > (MockBehavior.Strict);
        mockCreditDecisionService.Setup(p => p.GetCreditDecision(creditScore)).Returns(expectedResult);

        systemUnderTest = new CreditDecision(mockCreditDecisionService.Object);
        var result = systemUnderTest.MakeCreditDecision(creditScore);

        Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(expectedResult));

        mockCreditDecisionService.VerifyAll();
    }
}
```

I don't have implementation of `ICreditDecisionService`, yet **Moq** test passess! Could you explain what is wrong with these codes.

Comment: There does not seem to be anything wrong with your code. It is executing just as you configured it to run. You don't need an implementation that is why you are using a mock. The class under test `CreditDecision` is being injected with a mocked dependency to test the `MakeCreditDecision` method.

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I was trying to understand why we don't need ```if(creditScore) then return "Mabye" ..... ```. Not trying to achieve anything beside understanding Moq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your code is working exactly as designed/written. You're creating a mock of `ICreditDecisionService` and telling it what to return in each case. The test on the other hand is asserting two things happen:

1. `CreditDecision.MakeCreditDecision()` returns the value generated by the `ICreditDecisionService` (in this case mocked to always return a correct/known value).
2. Calling `CreditDecision.MakeCreditDecision()` calls `ICreditDecisionService.GetCreditDecision()` with the correct value of `creditScore`.

Therefore, your test is testing `CreditDecision` *not* `ICreditDecisionService`. You do not need an implementation of `ICreditDecisionService` to test `CreditDecision`; this is where the mock comes in. You're isolating `CreditDecision` from `ICreditDecisionService`, whatever the actual implementation might be, in order to test only `CreditDecision`.

I would, however, change the test name to reflect what's really happening in the test; perhaps something like `MakeCreditDecision_Returns_Result_From_Service` would be a better description.

Comment: We are not testing ```ICreditDecisionService```. This makes sense. Thank you!